# Termos de oração com "como" e concordância de número

Tags: sintaxe, concordância

Estou corrigindo um trabalho de um aluno (numa matéria que não é Português) e fiquei com dúvida com relação à concordância de número com a palavra "como".

Essencialmente, o aluno escreveu algo equivalente a

- Trataremos João e Pedro **como** adulto.

sob a premissa de que, como cada um de João e Pedro é um único adulto, a palavra adulto deve ser escrita no singular.

Do meu modo de entender, há discordância de número desse modo, pois "adulto" deveria concordar com "João e Pedro". Parece que, essencialmente, estamos omitindo alguns termos no meio da frase, que completa seria

- Trataremos João e Pedro **como** [se eles fossem] adultos.

em cujo caso ficaria mais claro que o objeto "adulto" deveria concordar com o sujeito "eles". Por outro lado, também haveria a possibilidade

- Trataremos João e Pedro **como** [se cada um deles fosse um] adulto.

Então ficam algumas dúvidas:

> Na frase "Trataremos João e Pedro como adultos", qual a função das seguintes partes?
>
> - "João e Pedro como adultos"
> - "como"
> - "adultos"
>
> e qual a concordância correta de "adulto[s]"?

Mais especificamente, a frase é parte de um exercício de Matemática; "Vamos escrever v e w como soma[s] de elementos de X e de Y", mas acredito que o exemplo que dei acima seja equivalente para os fins de concordância.

Comment: @Schilive Seria no primeiro sentido, tratando Pedro e João como adultos separadamente (mas ao mesmo tempo). Um exemplo mais específico do caso em questão (utilizando números naturais para simplificar, como você bem fez):
"Vamos escrever 4 e 6 como somas de números naturais: 4=2+2 e 6=1+5".A minha dúvida é qual é o papel de "como soma de elementos de X e Y" especificamente; complemento nominal? adjunto adverbial? Qual regra se aplica para determinar o plural ou singular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É *como adultos*, no plural:

> Trataremos João e Pedro *como adultos*

A meu ver, este *tratar* é um verbo transitivo predicativo, que seleciona um complemento direto (*João e Pedro*) e um predicativo desse complemento direto (*como adultos*). O teu exemplo é equivalente a:

> Trataremos João e Pedro *como sendo adultos*

Esta análise segue a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, tomo II, p. 1351), que apresenta, entre outros, estes exemplos:

> O Rui descreveu a chefe *como uma pessoa instável*
>
> Identificaram o problema *como muito sério*

e explica em nota de rodapé:

> Esta estruturas têm uma variante na qual o predicativo do complemento direto é introduzido pela forma gerundiva do verbo *ser*: cf., por exemplo, *o Rui descreveu a chefe *como sendo uma pessoa instável**.

A [Infopédia (dicionário da Porto Editora)](https://www.infopedia.pt/$predicativo), indica *tratar* como um verbo transitivo predicativo, e encontramos um exemplo neste [blog da Escola Secundária José Gomes Ferreira (Lisboa)](https://gavetadenuvens.blogspot.com/2017/08/aulas-3-periodo-2-parte-113.html):

> O professor tratou como sacaninhas os seus alunos

Aqui o predicativo (*como sacaninhas*) vem antes do complemento direto (*os seus alunos*), como acontece frequentemente nestas construções.

A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/$predicativo) diz explicitamente que o predicativo do complemento direto “concorda em género e número com” o complemento direto (eles chamam-lhe *objeto direto*, que é uma terminologia alternativa). Isto torna-se evidente na variante com o *sendo* explícito:

> Trataremos João e Pedro *como sendo adultos*

O sujeito implícito de *sendo* é recuperado da oração principal — *João e Pedro* — tornando claro que tem de ser *adultos*, pois o predicativo concorda em número com o seu sujeito. Para o sujeito implícito de *sendo* poder ser *cada um de João e Pedro*, para justificar o singular *adulto*, já teria de ser assim na oração principal, *trataremos cada um de João e Pedro*. Isto não mais que confirma a tua e minha intuição, que, vinda de de falantes nativos, nunca é de descurar.

---

### Discordâncias

Na verdade, a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/$predicativo) mais abaixo no mesmo artigo, citando a *Terminologia Linguística para os Ensinos Básico e Secundário*, diz apenas que é “regra geral” que “o predicativo do complemento direto concorda, em género e número, com o complemento direto”. Não dão exemplos de “discordâncias”, mas não são difíceis de imaginar. O verbo *ser* permite discordâncias de género e número: *Joana e Maria são um casal*. Logo também diremos, *trataremos Joana e Maria como um casal*.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta completa, e em especial pelas referências. Então, se entendi corretamente, em "Vamos escrever/descrever 4 e 6 como somas de números naturais" o "como somas de números naturais" também serve como predicativo do objeto "4 e 6", e o 'núcleo' (não sei se é a palavra correta) "somas" (usado como substantivo que requer complemento preposicionado) deve ser pluralizado?

Comment: @Questioner, sim. Esqueci-me de mencionar isso. "4 e 6" é complemento direto de "escrever", e "como somas de números naturais" (e não "soma") é o predicativo do complemento direto. Sim, "somas" é o núcleo do sintagma nominal "somas de números naturais".

Comment: @Questioner, curiosamente, soa-me bem "trataremos João e Pedro como o Bruno" (="como tratamos o Bruno"), que tem um sintaxe diferente; também "trataremos João e Pedro como **os** adultos", ... em "como adultos", sem "os", eu assumo um "sendo", não um "tratamos". mas não me entra "trataremos João e Pedro como (tratamos) um adulto". De qualquer modo isto resultaria disparatado no teu exemplo dos números: "trataremos 4 e 6 como tratamos a soma de dois números naturais"? Todos com muito amor e carinho?

Comment: Realmente, "como [tratamos] o Bruno"/"como [tratamos] os adultos" me soa mais como oração adverbial de modo, dando qualidade ao modo de tratamento (o mesmo que é aplicado ao Bruno/aos adultos) e não a João e a Pedro. Mesmo no singular, "trataremos Pedro como os adultos" me soa aceitável (embora não muito natural), e dá a entender de que Pedro será tratado do mesmo modo que adultos são tratados. A palavra "tratar" não soa bem com os números no exemplo dado, pois parece ter sentido de analogia e não de utilizar uma propriedade factual deles.

Answer (score 2):

Deve concordar e estar no plural: *adultos*.

Sua segunda opção exige um "[se cada um deles fosse um]" implícito que não se assumiria naturalmente num contexto geral. A ausência do plural é uma característica bem comum da linguagem coloquial e é ela deve estar se manifestando no texto do teu aluno, como mencionado [aqui](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/tal-qual-tem-plural.htm) para o caso do "tal qual".

Vale observar que se pode tratar "e Pedro" como um adendo, indicando com vírgulas (similarmente ao que se descreve [aqui](https://blogs.correiobraziliense.com.br/dad/concordancia-o-que-e/) para "assim/bem como"). Assim, as duas frases seguintes são válidas:

- Trataremos João, e Pedro, como adultos.
- Trataremos João, e Pedro, como adulto.

Exemplos similares, para concordância verbal, podem ser encontrados [aqui](https://www.tjsc.jus.br/web/servidor/dicas-de-portugues/-/asset_publisher/0rjJEBzj2Oes/content/concordancia-verbal-bem-como-da-mesma-forma-que-e-com-).

No caso da frase no teste de matemática, acho ainda mais importante usar o plural, para indicar que se tratam de somas em geral distintas.